# Geting specific value form a form in yii

Tags: php, yii

So just for my general knowledge about the yii framework i was trying to get a specific value from the form after it was submited, I manged to do it get the value buy doing the following

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Newsletter'];
echo $_POST['Newsletter']['email'];
```

Is there any other way to do it like a specific way to do it in the yii framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
echo $model->email;
```

because after populate the model using this:

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Newsletter'];
```

you have the model with the posted values.

Comment: Okay thank that work i did echo $model->after the $model->attributes=$_POST['Newsletter']; and it worded thank you :)